# Ways to make non-synchronized data structure thread safe

Tags: java, thread-safety, synchronized

I am wondering is there any other way to make a non-synchronized data structure to be thread safe other than using `synchronized` data structure like `Hashtable` and `Vector`, or using a wrapper like `Collections.synchronizedList(List<T> arg)` or `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map<K,V> arg)` ?

I was asked on the interview that how to make a hashmap thread safe, and I told him to use `Hashtable` or `ConcurrentHashMap` or use the `Collections.synchronizedMap` wrapper, however, seems like these answers is not what he is looking for

Comment: it depends on the data structure really. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Yes I updated my question slightly

Comment: Or use a ConcurrentHashMap, that uses CAS primitive instead of locks

Comment: I actually said ConcurrentHashMap and CopyonWriteArrayList instead of hashtable and vector

Comment: There is _no_ general-purpose way to make an arbitrary data structure immutable, except to lock the whole thing on each operation...or to make it read-only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can make it [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html). This is actually an excellent way to make code thread safe in many situations.

Comment: Can you give an example please ? lets say you want to make hashmap thread-safe

Comment: Basically all you have to do is to not expose any methods that alter the state of the `Map`, and make sure that every change to the `Map` results in a new `Map` being created. This isn't feasible for every situation, but when it is it saves you a lot of headache.

Comment: Several libraries have specialized immutable versions of collections -- e.g. Guava's [`ImmutableMap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained).

Comment: @Keppil Are you saying to make a defensive copy ? like deep copy of whatever you are returning from the map ?

Comment: The utility class `java.util.Collections` has methods that turn various collection classes into immutable collections. Look at the `unmodifiable*()` methods.

Comment: @user1389813: You will need to make an entirely new `Map` when a change is requested, so this would require a deep copy to be absolutely safe.

Comment: Then what happen if 2 threads access and modify the map at the same time ?

Comment: @user1389813: Then you probably need some synchronization and/or versioning solution to make sure nothing is lost.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you do the synchronization of the construct yourself. But this is not recommended for apparent reasons...

Comment: Why would this be not recommended? One of the main reasons for introducing `ArrayList` as a substitute for `Vector` is that the synchronization that's actually needed for an application is often at a higher level than individual function calls to a `Vector` instance. This is usually done either with `synchronized` blocks or by using lock objects (from java.util.concurrent.locs).

Comment: Yes I said it can be done that why. What I meant was that it is better to use one of the `synchronized` versions than try to do the synchronization himself.

Comment: Not...necessarily.  If you want to synchronize a whole bunch of operations together, the `synchronized` wrappers won't help you.

Comment: If what you _want_ is `synchronized(list) { list.add(a); list.add(b); list.remove(c); }`, then `Collections.synchronizedList` doesn't really benefit you much.  Only if you're interested in locking on only one operation at a time is it helpful.

Comment: Another example would be: if (!map.containsKey(key))
                               map.put(key, value);

Comment: @ChanderShivdasani:For this you have `ConcurentHashMap#putIfAbsent`

Comment: Well, yes, if you can use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.  But generally speaking, if you want to lock on an entire group of operations, you may need to do the synchronization yourself.